# How to get the default instance of a Serde struct

Tags: rust, serde

Let's consider the following sample code (my actual code have several tenths of fields):

```rust
fn empty_field() -> Result<f64, String> {
    Err(String::new())
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Record {
    #[serde(rename = "Apple", default)]
    a: f64,
    #[serde(rename = "Banana", default)]
    b: String,
    #[serde(rename = "Coconut", default = "empty_field")]
    c: Result<f64, String>,
}
```

Is it possible to get the the default instance based on Serde annotations, without defining it manually as follows?

```rust
let empty_record = Record {
    a: 0.0,
    b: String::new(),
    c: Err(String::new()),
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @BallpointBen and @cdhowie, this is my final implementation:

```rust
let empty_data = std::iter::empty::<((), ())>();
let empty_deserializer =
    serde::de::value::MapDeserializer::<_, serde::de::value::Error>::new(empty_data);
let empty_record =
    Record::deserialize(empty_deserializer).expect("empty record should deserialize correctly");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deserialize directly from an empty `HashMap`.

```rust
use serde::{
    de::value::{Error as SerdeError, MapDeserializer},
    Deserialize, Serialize,
}; // 1.0.193
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::error::Error;

// your definitions here

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let data = HashMap::<(), ()>::new(); // K, V types seem not to matter
    let record = Record::deserialize(MapDeserializer::<_, SerdeError>::new(data.into_iter()))?;
    println!("{record:?}");
    Ok(())
}
```

```
Record { a: 0.0, b: "", c: Err("") }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with an example?

Comment: Sorry, I had the syntax wrong. See my update.

Comment: Nice idea. Note that instead of a `HashMap` you can use anything that implements `Iterator` of 2-tuples (but that yields no items), such as `std::iter::empty::<((), ())>()`, which seems perfect for this scenario. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0b45e072f89a4d3c0f4ddbb24ca6e6a4

Comment: Just in case anybody else was wondering: an empty HashTable [does not allocate memory](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/src/hashbrown/raw/mod.rs.html#843-856).
The iterator idea by cdhowie still seems a bit nicer though.

Comment: @ChrisB I agree